# blender - how do I add a color to an object?

Tags: python, blender

When I try, nothing happens. I select a color and click the object and nothing.

Maybe a python command?

Comment: search for: blender add material, you can do it with python but first learn it the easy way.  At least in maya you can execute the actions and then see the commands equivalent in the script editor, I think blender can do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select an object.
2. In Button window (at bottom) select 'Shading' (a gray ball) and then 'Material buttons' (red ball)
3. In 'Link and pipeline', press 'Add new'.
4. Edit material color ('Col').

[See it http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/large/222981727.png?AWSAccessKeyId=0ZRYP5X5F6FSMBCCSE82&Expires=1294658484&Signature=jDJpFXu7QI/7vGbW9BwBgL0trBU%3D](http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/large/222981727.png?AWSAccessKeyId=0ZRYP5X5F6FSMBCCSE82&Expires=1294658484&Signature=jDJpFXu7QI/7vGbW9BwBgL0trBU%3D)

Comment: To switch between shading modes, press `Z` when the main geometry panel has focus.

Comment: @Fabián: oops, expired. I suspect the UI has changed since then, too. I should revisit this answer. I hope the idea still holds.

Answer (score 3):

As @9000 mentioned, you might not have a material linked.

If you open a TextEditor window, you should be able to paste this script:

```
from random import random
import Blender
from Blender import *

scn = Blender.Scene.GetCurrent()
ob  = scn.objects.active
m   = ob.getData(mesh=True)
if(len(m.materials) < 1):
    mat = Material.New('newMat')
    m.materials += [mat]
m.materials[0].rgbCol = [random(), random(), random()]


Blender.Redraw()
```

This should set random colours, if you have a material linked, otherwise creates a new material and links it.

Note that you need **Python installed** on **Windows** for the console, and you need to start Blender from **Terminal** on **OSX/Linux** to see the console.
Also, the snippet works for Blender *2.49*, **not** *2.5x*. You didn't mention which version of Blender you use.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use **vertex paint** in the options at the bottom:

[image: click for an image]